# Problem with Periodic tasks in django with Celery

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, celery, periodic-task

My periodic tasks with celery is not working. I wish to update my database every night depending on the date. here is my ptasks.py file in the application directiory:

```
'''
import datetime
import celery
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from django.utils import timezone
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=0, minute=0))
def every_night():
    tasks=Task.objects.all()
    form=TaskForm()
    if form.deadline<timezone.now() and form.staus=="ONGOING":
        form.status="PENDING"
        form.save()
'''
```

I am using ampq in settings.py:

```
'''
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER='djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
'''
```

Here is my models.py:

```
'''
from django.db import models
import datetime
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.
class Task(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    comment=models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    Tag1=models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Tag1")
    deadline=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    status=models.CharField(max_length=15,default="ONGOING")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
'''
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
'''
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import *

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Task
        fields='__all__'

'''
```

Comment: What is the output when running celery? Does it find your task? Not related to celery - but why are you using a form??

Comment: @ohrstrom my admin does find the task, I am using a form because i want to create a form/checklist  that updates and refreshes automatically every night.

Comment: you don't need a form to programmatically update an instance - forms are for user input (and validateion etc).
If you wan't to update a queryset by some conditions maybe use something like: 
`Task.objects.filter(deadline__lt=timezone.now(), status="ONGOING").update(status="PENDING")`
However - in this case I think it would make more sense to just filter the query directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

To update the database records as you're planning you could do like this:

`<your_app>/models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Task(models.Model):

    STATUS_PENDING = "pending"
    STATUS_ONGOING = "ongoing"

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_ONGOING, "ongoing"),
        (STATUS_PENDING, "pending"),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=15, default=STATUS_ONGOING, choices=STATUS_CHOICES
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`<your_app>/tasks.py`

```
from django.utils import timezone
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task

from .models import Task


@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=0, minute=0))
def every_night():

    qs = Task.objects.filter(deadline__lt=timezone.now(), status=Task.STATUS_ONGOING)

    # Update whole queryset at once
    qs.update(status=Task.STATUS_PENDING)

    # Alternatively update one by one (e.g. if you need signals to be fired)
    # for task in qs:
    #     task.status = Task.STATUS_PENDING
    #     task.save()
```

Make sure to run celery "beat" to trigger the periodic tasks:

```
celery -A app worker -B
```

## Solution 2

However - for the situation described, I honestly don't see the point why to take the detours to add information in a distinct database field that easily can be derived by each record anyway. This adds redundancy in the database itself and seems to be unneeded.

Why not just use a `Manager` to easily get the desired model instances?

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class TaskManager(models.Manager):
    def pending(self):
        return (
            self.get_queryset()
            .filter(deadline__lt=timezone.now())
            .exclude(complete=True)
        )


class Task(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = TaskManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And get the "pending" queryset: `Task.objects.pending()`